# Extending a controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I have a controller which calls out to another class.

```
class BlahController < ActionController
  def index
    OtherClass.get_stuff
  end
end
```

In this class I want to be able to write controller style code.

for instance:

```
class OtherClass
  def self.get_stuff
    @foo = bar
  end
end
```

However, I would also like `@foo` to exist when inside my view, but as it's a separate class those variables aren't making it back through into the controller assigns - so question is, how I can make this so?

*(Ignore why I'm having to call out to a separate class, I'm trying to get this code fitting in with a legacy codebase without too much butchery)*

Comment: are you dealing with lots of instance variables, if not simple return from your class and storing it in instance variable should be good to go

Comment: I don't want to return stuff as it limits what I can do with the class later on

Comment: How about you move your method - OtherClass.getStuff to a helper class so that it is accessible from view ?

Comment: Helpers are primarily view helpers, not controller and I don't really want to dirty those waters.

Comment: You are confused. There is no such thing as "controller style code". A controller is just a class. You're asking to set an instance variable from the return value of a method in another class. See my answer.

Comment: Does OtherClass has to be a class? What if you change OtherClass to a module and mix in it into the controller?

Answer (score 1):

```
class BlahController < ActionController
  def index
    OtherClass.get_stuff(self)
  end
end

class OtherClass
  def self.get_stuff(that)
    that.instance_variable_set(:@foo, bar)
  end
end
```

Please note that I don't agree with this method.  I am just answering the question as you stated it.

I would prefer to accomplish this functionality through mixins and thereby decrease parameter coupling that is present within the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Code structured like this will be difficult to read and maintain.  Whenever you can, let the controller *directly* set all of the variables that the view needs:

```
class BlahController < ActionController
  def index
    @foo = OtherClass.get_stuff
  end
end

class OtherClass
  def self.get_stuff
    # return the value that should be assigned to @foo  
  end
end
```